# NestedScrollView inside ConstraintLayout cannot be scrolled until bottom

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I have an activity like this:

[image]

Below the "Berapa jumlah kartu kredit" TextView, there's another TextView and Spinner, but cannot scroll further down.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebg"
    tools:context=".activity.Apply1Activity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvApply1_tv0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Input informasi pengajuan pinjaman"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvApply1_Pekerjaan"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Pekerjaan"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvApply1_tv0"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_pekerjaan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvApply1_Pekerjaan"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvApply1_NamaPerusahaan"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Nama perusahaan atau toko"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner_pekerjaan"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtApply1_NamaPerusahaan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvApply1_NamaPerusahaan" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvApply1_Email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edtApply1_NamaPerusahaan"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtApply1_Email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvApply1_Email" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvApply1_MulaiKerja"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Mulai bekerja sejak"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edtApply1_Email"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_worksince"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvApply1_MulaiKerja">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_month"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:entries="@array/arr_bulan"
                    />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_year"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvApply1_StatusPekerjaan"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Status pekerjaan"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ll_worksince"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_status_pekerjaan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvApply1_StatusPekerjaan"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvApply1_Income"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Penghasilan per bulan"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/spinner_status_pekerjaan"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtApply1_Income"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvApply1_Income" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvApply1_KK"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Berapa jumlah kartu kredit"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edtApply1_Income"
                />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_kk"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvApply1_KK"
                />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnApply1_Lanjut"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:background="@color/color_orange"
        android:text="Lanjut"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nsv1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> You need to change

1. NestedScrollview constraints.
2. NestedScrollview width and height
3. Reduce Button top margin

> I have updated your code and it's working now.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_white">

    <!--change Nested scrollview constraint, width and height-->
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnApply1_Lanjut"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            
            .....

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnApply1_Lanjut"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_blue_pin"
        android:text="Lanjut"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nsv1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly your **NestedScrollView** is not scrolling because you have set it's **height** to **match_parent**, Try with **wrap_content** it should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options:

1. Since you do not have any nested scrolling content inside the root scroll view. Try converting NestedScrollView to Scroll View.
   or
2. a. remove top constraint from button and add bottom constraint to the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnApply1_Lanjut"`

   b. replace match_parent with 0dp to actually match the constraint for nestedScrollView. Like this `android:layout_height="0dp"`